# Mockito Exception - when() requires an argument which has to be a method call on a mock

Tags: java, controller, mockito, spring-test

I have a very simple test case that is using Mockito and Spring Test framework. When I do

```
when(pcUserService.read("1")).thenReturn(pcUser);
```

I get this exception.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

    at com.project.cleaner.controller.test.PcUserControllerTest.shouldGetPcUser(PcUserControllerTest.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
```

I have tried with different methods but keep on getting this error message. I am using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE with Mockito. Please share and guide me in the right direction.

Comment: I've the same problem, but I'm using:
    @Autowired
    @ReplaceWithMock(beanName="logDao")
    private LogDao logDaoMock;

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You need to create a MOCK of pcUserService first, and then use that mock.

```
PcUserService mock = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(PcUserService.class);
when(mock.read("1")).thenReturn(pcUser);
```

Comment: But I can not debug in that case. do it actually calls that method?

Comment: @eatSleepCode: the REAL method `PcUserService.read` gets never invoke in this example. Instead an Mockito Mock gets invoked, and this mock return `pcUser`

Comment: yes, I am facing a issue with this, I have a service lets say `TestService` and it has a method `testMethod()` and code inside `testMethod` includes call to another service method for eg.   `AnotherTestService.getData()`. So in my case I am not able to mock `AnotherTestService` what should I do?

Comment: Why are you not able to replace `AnotherTestService` with an mock?

Comment: @eatSleepCode: Maybe you should have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20856647/280244

Comment: @Ralph i have a question
if the read method would be static than also do i need to mock the PcUserService class?

Comment: @nsu: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito

Comment: Is it correct to mock the class that I want to test in the junit?

Comment: When I don't mock it gives error "org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'."

Comment: @Hetal Rachh: you should not replace the functionality you want to test by an mock, because then you test the mock. But it is correct to replace some functionality that is used by the function you want to test with an mock. - So if you have an Class with two methods A and B, A contains a lot of stuff you want to test, but A also invoke B and you are not able to execute B in your Test environment, then it is ok to replace B by an mock (but not A)

Comment: @Hetal Rachh: your second commend sounds like a new question. Please raise a new question with more details. So somebody else can also help you to find a good answer.

Comment: Thanks @Ralph. I will raise a new question for my query.

Comment: Any idea if someone trying to return a list instead of Object?

Comment: @Satyaprakash Nayak: `when(...).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(element1, element2));`

Answer (score 37):

In case others hit this issue....

It could also be the case that the method you are trying to mock out,`pcUserService.read`, is declared as a `final` method.  From what I've noticed this appears to cause issues with Mockito.

Comment: The diagnostic is ok, but what is the solution :p

Comment: @amdev Don't make `pcUserService.read` final :)  Not ideal I know, but there's not a whole lot you can do about it.  Mockito can't mock a final method.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking for more detail and possible workarounds

Comment: Actually, sometimes you don't mock your own class but some class from an external dependencies. But it's ok I found how to mock final method with mockito https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito/14307615

Answer (score 26):

If you use `Kotlin`, you should know that methods are `final` by default. So write `open fun` instead of `fun`. Thanks to @djkelly99 for a tip.

Comment: Thank this worked. But 1 question. How would I solve this issue without making the method and class as `open`

Comment: @viper, thanks! I don't use tests now, but suppose, you should use newer version of this library. If I am not mistaken, it supports `final` methods. Probably you can try to create interfaces or abstract classes.

Comment: I have latest version of `mockito` but I am still having the issue. What are the drawbacks of using an `open` modifier?

Comment: @viper, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292863/how-to-mock-a-final-class-with-mockito, https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2, https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito.

Comment: @viper, it means that descendants of your `open` class may change a behavior in a way you didn't expect. Overriden methods can access those collections you didn't want to access. Or even change collections, objects. See also https://www.quora.com/What-are-all-the-advantages-of-inheritance-in-Java, https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-disadvantages-of-inheritance-in-Java.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution to this issue might be that in case of a test class that is using `PowerMockRunner`, you might have to add the class that you are mocking to the list, in `@PrepareForTest` annotation.

For instance -

`@PrepareForTest({ PcUserService.class })`

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had, but I actually added the interface to the @preparefortest list, not the class, this answer made me double check there.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was solved by injecting `@MockBean`.

For ex.

```
@MockBean
StateRepository mockStateRepository;
```

Answer (score 4):

There's another possible reason for such error - sometimes IDE prefers to statically import Mockito.when() from another package:

```
import static io.codearte.catchexception.shade.mockito.Mockito.when;
```

vs

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when; //should normally use this one
```

The thing is 'when' from io.codearte package is compliant with org.mockito.Mockito.any() on compilation level, but fails during runtime with that exact same error message.

Answer (score 4):

If you get this exception when using `MockedStatic` or `Mockito.mockStatic`, it can also mean that you are mixing matchers and literals in the call to the static method.

Try changing any mixes like `YourClass.staticMethod(any(), "literal")` to `YourClass.staticMethod(any(), eq("literal"))`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, the method that I was trying to mock it was a final method. I removed the modifier and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

For the help of others who stuck with the same problem;

The method you are trying to mock , pcUserService.read, is declared as a **final** method. Static methods appears to cause issues with Mockito.

Answer (score 1):

Basically You need to use the PowerMockito.mockStatic to enable static mocking for all static methods of a class. This means make it possible to stub them using the when-thenReturn syntax.
For example: 
`PowerMockito.mockStatic(TestClass.class);
 when(TestClass.getString()).thenReturn("HelloWorld!");`

Note: you have to add `@PrepareForTest({ TestClass.class })` to your unit test class.

Answer (score 1):

When I got this exception, I was using @InjectMocks on the class that I needed to have the @Mock objects injected into (via constructor injection).

AFter much searching, I finally stumbled across this article:

https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/mockito-when-requires-an-argument-which-has-to-be-a-method-call-on-a-mock/

The key part to take away from it is (from the article):

> When Mockito see this @InjectMocks, it doesn’t mock it, it just
> creates a normal instance, so the when() will be failed.

So this make this exception message I was getting

> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.

make sense now; you aren't using *when* on an actual mock but an actual instance.

The link also provides the solution to the problem:

> To solve it, annotate @Spy to mock it partially.

On top of @InjectMocks, put @Spy.

As a side note, if you try to make it a Mock by putting @Mock on top of @InjectMocks, you will get exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: This combination of
> annotations is not permitted on a single field: @Mock and @InjectMocks

Using @Spy on top of @InjectMocks solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue. You can simply use the “spy” annotation on the “pcUserService” bean, if you cannot mock the “pcUserService” bean (e.g. when the “pcUserService” bean itself is under test and has @InjectMocks annotation). Briefly, “spy” means you mock the bean partially.

The [Mockito – when() requires an argument which has to be ‘a method call on a mock’](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/mockito-when-requires-an-argument-which-has-to-be-a-method-call-on-a-mock/) is so great and makes the point in a nutshell with a simple and useful example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use KOIN, include in the gradle's dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:2.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when mocking static method of anotherClass called inside  testing a method of someClass. In that case, we need to add @PrepareForTest({anotherClass.class, someClass.class}) both the class having the static method and caller class.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and it was because the mocked object is defined as `@Bean`and the overriden `@Bean` in the test was not working because of a missing spring property value

```
@Bean
@Primary
public JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil() {
    return Mockito.mock(JwtTokenUtil.class);
}

@Autowired
private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

when(jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken)).thenReturn(true);
```

**Fix**

`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`  in application-test.properties

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to attach the  attach the Mockito extension to the Class

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class pcUserService{
 ... 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if anything above answers your case, then check that you did missed the `@Test` annotation for your test method.

```
@Test
public void my_test_method(){
}
```

just quoting, as this was my case. just missed the annotation.