# Getting an exception while Junit tests

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am making a junit test for a module.

```
when(myDetailsFacade.getMyDetailsInfo(anyLong())).thenReturn(null);
mrc.getFlowScoe().put("action", "create");
try{
    instance.initialiseForm(mrc, mpr);
   }catch (Exception e){
      fail("Shouldn't get here");
   }
model=(MyDetailsForm)mrc.getFlowScope().get("myDetailsFormModel");
assertNotNull(model);
assertEquals(model.getNationality(), "USA");
```

and i am getting this error

```
org.mockito.excetions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when()requires an argument which has to be a method call on a mock.
For example
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
```

in out facade we are getting hardcode value, like.

```
private myDetails getMyDetailsData{
myDetails.setNationality("USA");
return myDetails;
}
```

this is my initialiseform method which i am trying to test.

```
public void initialiseForm (RequestContext requestContext, PortletRequest portletRequest){

requestContext.getFlowScope().put("getTitles", getTitles);
requestContext.getFlowScope().put("getGender", getGender);

BasicModel model = (BasicModel)requestContext.getFlowScope().get("BasicModel");
if(model == null){
model = new BasicModel();
}

model.setEmpName("Edward");
}
```

And here is the getTitles method in same java file.

```
private Map <String, String> getTitles(){

option.put("Dr", "Dr");
option.put("Mr", "Mr");
return option;

}
```

Comment: Can you post a greater portion of your code surrounding the call on the mock?

Comment: How are you creating `myDetailsFacade`?

Comment: Facade is nothing we are just getting the hard code value from facade

Comment: `myDetailsFacade` should be a mock object of some sort - [See the docs](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#when(T)) for more info.

Comment: @Edd check the code again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mockito Exception - when() requires an argument which has to be a method call on a mock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186604/mockito-exception-when-requires-an-argument-which-has-to-be-a-method-call-on)

Answer (score 0):

As hinted at in the exception you've received, the [`when()`](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#when(T)) static method is for stubbing *methods on mock objects*. You need `myDetailsFacade` to be a mock if you want to stub the result of a method call. Try something like (with the actual type of `myDetailsFacade` of course):

```
MyDetails myDetailsFacade= mock(MyDetails.class)
when(myDetailsFacade.getMyDetailsInfo(anyLong())).thenReturn(null);
```

Comment: I tried that but getting same error, Please check the question again i put the code snippet which i want to test.

Comment: @Akash I still don't see the place where you assign a value to `myDetailsFacade`. Can you provide the full details of the test that doesn't work.

Comment: Please take a look of my initialiseForm public method at above code i want to make a junit test for that.

Comment: And take a look of this also http://akashjaiswalliferay.blogspot.in/2015/08/test.html

Comment: @Akash I think there's already enough information about the code that's being tested - the thing that would be useful is to see the full test, not just the snippet you've provided.

Comment: i have given the link where i have provided all the code

Comment: @Akash I don't see the the `when(myDetailsFacade.getMyDetailsInfo(anyLong())).thenReturn(null);` line (i.e. the one that has the problem) anywhere there. That's what I want more context of.