# Mockito Exception when mocking

Tags: java, junit, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

When I try to run the following test

```
public class FavoriteServiceTest extends AbstractCoreTest {

    @Autowired
    private FavoriteRepository favoriteRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RevisionService revisionService;

    @Autowired
    private FavoriteService favoriteService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(revisionService.getGlobalRevisionNumber()).thenReturn(1L);
    }

    @Test
    public void loadFavorites() throws Exception {
        when(favoriteRepository.findFavoritesByUserId("123")).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
        List<Favorite> favorites = favoriteService.loadFavorites(123L);

        assertThat(favorites.size(), is(0));
    }
```

I get the following exception, but im pretty sure the mock is correct initialized

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
>   1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.    Mocking methods
>   declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
>   2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
>
> at FavoriteServiceTest.setUp(FavoriteServiceTest.java:44)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)

Comment: check the below link it will be help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186604/mockito-exception-when-requires-an-argument-which-has-to-be-a-method-call-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace @Autowired with @Mock -.-

```
@Mock
private DocumentService documentService;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `favoriteRepository` should be a mock object, benfinit from spring boot, you can using `@MockBean` here.