# when I run mockito test occurs WrongTypeOfReturnValue Exception

Tags: java, mockito

Error detail:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Boolean cannot be returned by updateItemAttributesByJuId()
updateItemAttributesByJuId() should return ResultRich
This exception might occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
```

my code :

```
@InjectMocks
protected ItemArrangeManager arrangeManagerSpy = spy(new ItemArrangeManagerImpl());
@Mock
protected JuItemWriteService juItemWriteService;

when(arrangeManagerSpy
    .updateItemAttributes(mapCaptor.capture(), eq(juId), eq(itemTO.getSellerId())))
    .thenReturn(false);
```

As you can see, I am calling `when` on `updateItemAttributes` (which does return a `boolean`) not on `updateItemAttributesByJuId`.

1. Why is Mockito attempting to return a `boolean` from `updateItemAttributesByJuId`?
2. How can this be rectified?

Answer (score 298):

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mockito/9WUvkhZUy90, you should rephrase your

```
when(bar.getFoo()).thenReturn(fooBar)
```

to

```
doReturn(fooBar).when(bar).getFoo()
```

Comment: This is great tip. I was also having this issue when testing some Spring `@Repository` DAO method with **@Aspect**. if i do `when(someDao.someMethod()).thenReturn(List<xxx>)`, I got this WrongTypeOfReturnValue exception. Thru debug, I can see that the `someMethod` method is actually been called in the above statement and triggers the Around Advice and return a `null` but Mockito is expecting a `List<xxx>`.

Comment: Worked also for me! Thanks! Although, I didn't fully understand the explanation in the link provided.

Comment: What if the method to be mocked is `static`?

Comment: @paradocslover in case of static I think you got to use Powermockt  Powermock.mockStatic(foo.class) and then PowerMockito.when(Foo.class, "method", ...params).thenReturn(bar)

Comment: For me unfortunately does not give anything. I am using that for spy. Still crashing, the only option is to reorder instructing spies and mocks

Comment: I am getting Argument passed to when() is not a mock! after above change.

Comment: we cannot use this solution if we are using `@InjectMocks` , working with only `@Mock`.

Comment: You should explain why this works in your answer, instead of giving us a link to read.

Answer (score 47):

Very interested problem.
In my case this problem was caused when I tried to debug my tests on this similar line:

```
Boolean fooBar;
when(bar.getFoo()).thenReturn(fooBar);
```

The important note is that the tests were running correctly without debugging.

In any way, when I replaced above code with below code snippet then I was able to debug the problem line without problems.

```
doReturn(fooBar).when(bar).getFoo();
```

Comment: Thanks, It looks like there is the same issue with Kotlin data classes as fields, and your solution solved it!

Comment: Thank you, I had the same issue with Kotlin and Android

Comment: Thanks, this helped with fixing debugging issues!

Comment: I started getting "Argument passed to when() is not a mock!" error after above mentioned change.

Comment: I had this issue when return value was generic value, e.g., `Result<String>`.  "Reverse order" worked fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly my problem. (Debugging)

Comment: given(ff2Service.isNewServiceEnabled()).willReturn(false); syntax was flakey (failing inconsistantly) not sure why, however when I put put in doReturn synax as per this post, it worked. i.e. changed it to  doReturn(false).when(ff2Service).isNewServiceEnabled();

Answer (score 45):

Another reason for similar error message is trying to mock a `final` method. One shouldn't attempt to mock final methods (see [Final method mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking)).

I have also confronted the error in a multi-threaded test. Answer by gna worked in that case.

Answer (score 10):

For me this meant I was running this:

```
a = Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class);
b = new RealClass();
when(b.method1(a)).thenReturn(c); 
// within this method1, it calls param1.method2() -- note, b is not a spy or mock
```

So what was happening is that mockito was detecting that `a.method2()` was being called, and telling me I couldn't return `c` from `a.method2()` which is wrong.

Fix: use the `doReturn(c).when(b).method1(a)` style syntax (instead of `when(b.method1(a)).thenReturn(c);`), which will help you discover the hidden bug more concisely and quickly.

Or in this particular case, after doing that it started showing the more accurate "NotAMockException", and I changed it to not longer try to set a return value from a non-mock object.

Comment: Same mistake I also did. I mocked the method used in method1, executed and got this exception. It got resolved once I removed that code.

Comment: I think I am doing the same: setting a list to a field of a real object, and then `mock.doSth().getList()` while `mock.doSth()` returns the real object.

Answer (score 6):

I recently had this issue. The problem was that the method I was trying to mock had no access modifier. Adding public solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I had this error because in my test I had two expectations, one on a mock and one on concrete type

```
MyClass cls = new MyClass();
MyClass cls2 = Mockito.mock(Myclass.class);
when(foo.bar(cls)).thenReturn(); // cls is not actually a mock
when(foo.baz(cls2)).thenReturn();
```

I fixed it by changing cls to be a mock as well

Comment: so it can be the case that the error pops up with some hints but the true case is quite different.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was caused by trying to mock a static method and forgetting to call `mockStatic` on the class. Also I forgot to include the class into the `@PrepareForTest()`

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** If some arguments in your test are `null`, be sure to mock the parameter call with `isNull()` instead of `anyXXX()`.

---

I got this error when upgrading from Spring boot 1.5.x to 2.1.x. Spring boot ships with its own Mockito, which is now also upgraded to 2.x (see e.g. [Dependencies of Spring boot 2.1.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html))

Mockito has changed the behavior for the `anyXXX()` method, where `XXX` is `String`, `Long`, etc. Here is the javadoc of `anyLong()`:

> Since Mockito 2.1.0, only allow valued `Long`, thus
> `null` is not anymore a valid value As primitive wrappers
> are nullable, the suggested API to **match**
> `null` wrapper would be `#isNull()`. We felt this change
> would make tests harness much safer that it was with Mockito
> 1.x.

I'd suggest you debug to the point where your mock is about to be called and inspect, whether **at least one** argument is `null`. In that case make sure, that you prepare your mock with `isNull()` instead of e.g. `anyLong()`.

So this:

```
when(MockedClass.method(anyString());
```

becomes:

```
when(MockedClass.method(isNull());
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using both `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`. When I removed `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` it worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using annotations, may be you need to use @Mock instead of @InjectMocks. Because @InjectMocks works as @Spy and @Mock together. And @Spy keeps track of recently executed methods and you may feel that incorrect data is returned/subbed.

Comment: "`@InjectMocks` works as  `@Spy` and `@Mock` together." <- that seems wrong to me. Where did you heard this from?

Answer (score 1):

Error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:
>   String cannot be returned by size()
>   size() should return int
>   ***
>   If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
>   Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
>   1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded
>   tests.
>   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
>   2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to
>   stub spies -
>   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for
>   Mockito.spy() method.

Actual Code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Object.class, ByteString.class})

@Mock
private ByteString mockByteString;

String testData = “dsfgdshf”;
PowerMockito.when(mockByteString.toStringUtf8()).thenReturn(testData); 
// throws above given exception
```

Solution to fix this issue:

1st Remove annotation “@Mock”.

```
private ByteString mockByteString;
```

2nd Add `PowerMockito.mock`

```
mockByteString = PowerMockito.mock(ByteString.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this issue while mocking a function in a *Kotlin data class*. For some unknown reason one of my test runs ended up in a frozen state. When I ran the tests again some of my tests that had previously passed started to fail with the `WrongTypeOfReturnValue` exception.

I ensured I was using `org.mockito:mockito-inline` to avoid the issues with final classes (mentioned by Arvidaa), but the problem remained. What solved it for me was to **kill the process and restart Android Studio**. This terminated my frozen test run and the following test runs passed without issues.

Answer (score 1):

Missing @MockBean on the bean you want to mock

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue `WrongTypeOfReturnValue` because I mocked a method returning a `java.util.Optional;` with a `com.google.common.base.Optional;` due to my formatter automatically adding missing imports.

Mockito was just saying me that "method something() should return Optional"...

Answer (score 1):

In my case the bean has been initialized using *@Autowired* annotation instead of *@MockBean*

So in this way mocking of DAOs and Services throws such exception

Comment: Yes, in my case a Spring-Boot application Service test, MockBean should be used when mocking a Bean. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue were the multithreaded tests that were doing stubbing/verification on a shared mocks. It leaded to randomly throwing `WrongTypeOfReturnValue` exception.

This is not properly written test using Mockito.
Mocks should not be accessed from multiple threads.

The solution was to make mocks local to each test.

Answer (score 1):

## Android

In my case, or rather `Android` project's instrumentation tests:

- One time, I just needed to remove the `build` directory (to force rebuild).
- Another time, computer went out of memory, causing issues to all open Apps, and restarting each App was enough (without need to restart computer).

Maybe there are too many reasons for one single error!
(they should fix this already).

But I hope this helps someone
d= (◕‿↼ )

> Nowadays, because command-line does things better than IDE,
> I load command-line created `test-result.pb` file in IDE later
> (after all tests finish).

Comment: One year later, this saved my day, where I didn't even remember adding such answer.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, it turns out that the type of mocked object is actually an abstract interface, the issue gets resolved after changing the type to some implementation class,

Change

```
@Mock
private Proxy proxy;
```

to

```
@Mock
private ProxyImpl proxy;
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem!
I created a spy on my function and stubbed it like the following:

Create Spy

```
fktSpy: Class = Mockito.spy(class)
```

Stubbing

```
Mockito.doReturn(value).`when`(fktSpy).function()
```

Code is written in Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

This is my case:

```
//given
ObjectA a = new ObjectA();
ObjectB b = mock(ObjectB.class);
when(b.call()).thenReturn(a);

Target target = spy(new Target());
doReturn(b).when(target).method1();

//when
String result = target.method2();
```

Then I get this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
ObjectB$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$2eaf7d1d cannot be returned by method2()
method2() should return String
```

Can you guess?

The problem is that Target.method1() is a static method. Mockito completely warns me to another thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Scala and I've got this message where I've mistakenly shared a Mock between two `Object`s. So, be sure that your tests are independent of each other. The parallel test execution obviously creates some flaky situations since the objects in Scala are singleton compositions.