# Unit testing android application with retrofit and rxjava

Tags: android, mocking, mockito, rx-java, retrofit2

I have developed an android app that is using retrofit with rxJava, and now I'm trying to set up the unit tests with Mockito but I don't know how to mock the api responses in order to create tests that do not do the real calls but have fake responses.

For instance, I want to test that the method syncGenres is working fine for my SplashPresenter. My classes are as follow:

```
public class SplashPresenterImpl implements SplashPresenter {

private SplashView splashView;

public SplashPresenterImpl(SplashView splashView) {
    this.splashView = splashView;
}

@Override
public void syncGenres() {
    Api.syncGenres(new Subscriber<List<Genre>>() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            if(splashView != null) {
                splashView.onError();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Genre> genres) {
            SharedPreferencesUtils.setGenres(genres);
            if(splashView != null) {
                splashView.navigateToHome();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

the Api class is like:

```
public class Api {
    ...
    public static Subscription syncGenres(Subscriber<List<Genre>> apiSubscriber) {
        final Observable<List<Genre>> call = ApiClient.getService().syncGenres();
        return call
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(apiSubscriber);
    }

}
```

Now I'm trying to test the SplashPresenterImpl class but I don't know how to do that, I should do something like:

```
public class SplashPresenterImplTest {

@Mock
Api api;
@Mock
private SplashView splashView;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Callback<List<Genre>>> cb;

private SplashPresenterImpl splashPresenter;

@Before
public void setupSplashPresenterTest() {
    // Mockito has a very convenient way to inject mocks by using the @Mock annotation. To
    // inject the mocks in the test the initMocks method needs to be called.
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    // Get a reference to the class under test
    splashPresenter = new SplashPresenterImpl(splashView);
}

@Test
public void syncGenres_success() {

    Mockito.when(api.syncGenres(Mockito.any(ApiSubscriber.class))).thenReturn(); // I don't know how to do that

    splashPresenter.syncGenres();
    Mockito.verify(api).syncGenres(Mockito.any(ApiSubscriber.class)); // I don't know how to do that



}
}
```

Do you have any idea about how should I mock and verify the api responses? 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Following @invariant suggestion, now I'm passing a client object to my presenter, and that api returns an Observable instead of a Subscription. However, I'm getting a NullPointerException on my Subscriber when doing the api call. The test class looks like:

```
public class SplashPresenterImplTest {
@Mock
Api api;
@Mock
private SplashView splashView;

private SplashPresenterImpl splashPresenter;

@Before
public void setupSplashPresenterTest() {
    // Mockito has a very convenient way to inject mocks by using the @Mock annotation. To
    // inject the mocks in the test the initMocks method needs to be called.
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    // Get a reference to the class under test
    splashPresenter = new SplashPresenterImpl(splashView, api);
}

@Test
public void syncGenres_success() {
    Mockito.when(api.syncGenres()).thenReturn(Observable.just(Collections.<Genre>emptyList()));


    splashPresenter.syncGenres();


    Mockito.verify(splashView).navigateToHome();
}
}
```

Why am I getting that NullPointerException?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## How to test RxJava and Retrofit

### 1. Get rid of the static call - use dependency injection

The first problem in your code is that you use static methods. This is not a testable architecture, at least not easily, because it makes it harder to mock the implementation.
To do things properly, instead of using `Api` that accesses `ApiClient.getService()`, inject this **service** to the presenter through the constructor:

```
public class SplashPresenterImpl implements SplashPresenter {

private SplashView splashView;
private final ApiService service;

public SplashPresenterImpl(SplashView splashView, ApiService service) {
    this.splashView = splashView;
    this.apiService = service;
}
```

### 2. Create the test class

Implement your JUnit test class and initialize the presenter with mock dependencies in the `@Before` method:

```
public class SplashPresenterImplTest {

@Mock
ApiService apiService;

@Mock
SplashView splashView;

private SplashPresenter splashPresenter;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.splashPresenter = new SplashPresenter(splashView, apiService);
}
```

### 3. Mock and test

Then comes the actual mocking and testing, for example:

```
@Test
public void testEmptyListResponse() throws Exception {
    // given
    when(apiService.syncGenres()).thenReturn(Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());
    // when
    splashPresenter.syncGenres();
    // then
    verify(... // for example:, verify call to splashView.navigateToHome()
}
```

That way you can test your Observable + Subscription, if you want to test if the Observable behaves correctly, subscribe to it with an instance of `TestSubscriber`.

---

## Troubleshooting

When testing with RxJava and RxAndroid schedulers, such as `Schedulers.io()` and `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` you might encounter several problems with running your observable/subscription tests.

### NullPointerException

The first is `NullPointerException` thrown on the line that applies given scheduler, for example:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // throws NPE
```

The cause is that `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` is internally a `LooperScheduler` that uses android's `Looper` thread. This dependency is not available on JUnit test environment, and thus the call results in a NullPointerException.

### Race condition

The second problem is that if applied scheduler uses a separate worker thread to execute observable, the race condition occurs between the thread that executes the `@Test` method and the said worker thread. Usually it results in test method returning before observable execution finishes.

### Solutions

Both of the said problems can be easily solved by supplying test-compliant schedulers, and there are few options:

1. Use `RxJavaHooks` and `RxAndroidPlugins` API to override any call to `Schedulers.?` and `AndroidSchedulers.?`, forcing the Observable to use, for example, `Scheduler.immediate()`:

   ```
   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
           // Override RxJava schedulers
           RxJavaHooks.setOnIOScheduler(new Func1<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
               @Override
               public Scheduler call(Scheduler scheduler) {
                   return Schedulers.immediate();
               }
           });

           RxJavaHooks.setOnComputationScheduler(new Func1<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
               @Override
               public Scheduler call(Scheduler scheduler) {
                   return Schedulers.immediate();
               }
           });

           RxJavaHooks.setOnNewThreadScheduler(new Func1<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
               @Override
               public Scheduler call(Scheduler scheduler) {
                   return Schedulers.immediate();
               }
           });

           // Override RxAndroid schedulers
           final RxAndroidPlugins rxAndroidPlugins = RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance();
           rxAndroidPlugins.registerSchedulersHook(new RxAndroidSchedulersHook() {
               @Override
               public Scheduler getMainThreadScheduler() {
                   return Schedulers.immediate();
           }
       });
   }

   @After
   public void tearDown() throws Exception {
       RxJavaHooks.reset();
       RxAndroidPlugins.getInstance().reset();
   }
   ```

   This code has to wrap the Observable test, so it can be done within `@Before` and `@After` as shown, it can be put into JUnit `@Rule` or placed anywhere in the code. Just don't forget to reset the hooks.
2. Second option is to provide explicit `Scheduler` instances to classes (Presenters, DAOs) through dependency injection, and again just use `Schedulers.immediate()` (or other suitable for testing).
3. As pointed out by @aleien, you can also use an injected `RxTransformer` instance that executes `Scheduler` application.

I've used the first method with good results in production.

Comment: Thank you very much, and how could I test both success and error cases?

Comment: For error testing you can use `Observable.error(Throwable throwable)` factory method, for example `when(apiService.syncGenres()).thenReturn(new RuntimeException());`. If you want to be more specific about the error, use retrofit's `HttpException`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I've updated my answer, after using an api object and passing it to my presenter, I am getting a nullpointerexception error on my subscriber. What is going on? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the stack trace of the excepion? How does your presenter look now? Possible reasons are: you are using additional depenencies that you forgot to mock; you are using `Schedulers.io()` or similar (there are ways to enforce execution on `Schedulers.immediate()` that will do the job, for example by injecting the scheduler instance or using `RxJavaHooks` - @aleien pointed that out so refer to links in the answer)

Comment: As you say, I'm using: .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) which is what is causing the issue. I guess I have to remove that line of code when executed from unit testing, but I'm not sure how

Comment: Wow, this is one of the most detailed responses I've seen in recent time. Well done!

Comment: Hi @maciekjanusz I am trying do to that, but I am receiving this error: ScalarSynchronousObservable cannot be returned by getApi() I already modified RxJavaHooks and RxAndroidPlugin as you showed. How can I do?

Comment: @Lücks this is probably due to misuse of Mockito's api - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11520080/4191629). If that's not the case, I'll need more information: some fragment of code and possibly lib versions

Comment: Hi @maciekjanusz I already tried to do that :( I had to update my reactive to 1.1.7 to modify the RxJavaHooks. I am trying to do this: when(mUserService.getApi().getUsers()).thenReturn(rx.Observable.just(Collections.<User>emptyList()));

Comment: @Lücks it's probably best if you opened your own question with all necessary code excerpts and explanation

Comment: @maciekjanusz I created a new question, could you help me please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537482/unittesting-rxjava-methods

Comment: As @maciekjanusz said, the first option works well. Here is a TestRule for that : https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate/blob/master/app/src/test/java/uk/co/ribot/androidboilerplate/util/RxSchedulersOverrideRule.java and you can include it like this `@Rule
    public final RxSchedulersOverrideRule overrideSchedulersRule = new RxSchedulersOverrideRule();`

Answer (score 2):

Make your `syncGenres` method return `Observable` instead of `Subscription`. Then you can mock this method to return `Observable.just(...)` instead of making a real api call.

If you'd like to keep `Subscription` as returned value in that method (which I don't advise as it breaks `Observable` composability) you'd need to make this method not static, and pass whatever `ApiClient.getService()` returns as a constructor parameter and use mocked service object in tests (this technique is called Dependency Injection)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you return Subscription from your api methods? It is usually more handy to return Observable (or Single) from api methods (especially regarding to Retrofit being able to generate Observables and Singles instead of calls). If there is no special reason, I'd recommend to switch to something like this:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("genres")
    Single<List<Genre>> syncGenres();
    ...
}
```

so your calls to api will look like:

```
...
Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);
api.syncGenres()
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .observeOn(AndroidSheculers.mainThread())
   .subscribe(genres -> soStuff());
```

In that way, you'd be able to mock api class and write:

```
List<Genre> mockedGenres = Arrays.asList(genre1, genre2...);
Mockito.when(api.syncGenres()).thenReturn(Single.just(mockedGenres));
```

Also you'll have to consider that you won't be able to test responses on worker threads, since tests won't wait for them. For bypassing this problem I'd [recommend](http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2015/09/13/testing-rxjava-observables-subscriptions/) [reading](http://alexismas.com/blog/2015/05/20/unit-testing-rxjava/) [these](https://labs.ribot.co.uk/unit-testing-rxjava-6e9540d4a329#.uccla3dh8) [articles](http://macoscope.com/blog/unit-testing-rxjava/) and consider using something like scheduler manager or [transformer](https://gist.github.com/aleien/b6ed397fee338e6c60a7c2df9975cc47) to be able to explicitly tell presenter which schedulers to use (real or test ones)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll take a look at what you're saying. One question, why would you use Single instead of Observable? Thanks a lot

Comment: Usually you don't receive sequence of events from api response, just one chunk of data (even if that data is a list (: ). That what Single is - only one emitted object. You may use Observable, it's really ok, but Single is more specific to tell what your intent is - that you are waiting only for one object. Also if you'd like to create your own by using Single.create() you'll need to implement less methods.

 tldr: it's more specific than the Observable (:

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have an example to learn how to user RxTransformer.java?

Comment: You just pass it to presenter and instead of writing .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()... use .compose(rxTransformer.chainSchedulers()), like this: https://gist.github.com/aleien/52a079138156570017d64d2dbd8b627e

Answer (score 1):

I use these classes:

1. Service
2. RemoteDataSource
3. RemoteDataSourceTest
4. TopicPresenter
5. TopicPresenterTest

Simple Service:

```
public interface Service {
    String URL_BASE = "https://guessthebeach.herokuapp.com/api/";

    @GET("topics/")
    Observable<List<Topics>> getTopicsRx();

}
```

For RemoteDataSource

```
public class RemoteDataSource implements Service {

    private Service api;

    public RemoteDataSource(Retrofit retrofit) {


        this.api = retrofit.create(Service.class);
    }


    @Override
    public Observable<List<Topics>> getTopicsRx() {
        return api.getTopicsRx();
    }
}
```

The key is [MockWebServer from okhttp3](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver).

This library makes it easy to test that your app Does The Right Thing when it makes HTTP and HTTPS calls. It lets you specify which responses to return and then verify that requests were made as expected.

Because it exercises your full HTTP stack, you can be confident that you’re testing everything. You can even copy & paste HTTP responses from your real web server to create representative test cases. Or test that your code survives in awkward-to-reproduce situations like 500 errors or slow-loading responses.

Use MockWebServer the same way that you use mocking frameworks like Mockito:

Script the mocks.
Run application code.
Verify that the expected requests were made.
Here’s a complete example in RemoteDataSourceTest:

```
public class RemoteDataSourceTest {

    List<Topics> mResultList;
    MockWebServer mMockWebServer;
    TestSubscriber<List<Topics>> mSubscriber;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Topics topics = new Topics(1, "Discern The Beach");
        Topics topicsTwo = new Topics(2, "Discern The Football Player");
        mResultList = new ArrayList();
        mResultList.add(topics);
        mResultList.add(topicsTwo);

        mMockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        mSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void serverCallWithError() {
        //Given
        String url = "dfdf/";
        mMockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody(new Gson().toJson(mResultList)));
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(mMockWebServer.url(url))
                .build();
        RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource = new RemoteDataSource(retrofit);

        //When
        remoteDataSource.getTopicsRx().subscribe(mSubscriber);

        //Then
        mSubscriber.assertNoErrors();
        mSubscriber.assertCompleted();
    }

    @Test
    public void severCallWithSuccessful() {
        //Given
        String url = "https://guessthebeach.herokuapp.com/api/";
        mMockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody(new Gson().toJson(mResultList)));
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(mMockWebServer.url(url))
                .build();
        RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource = new RemoteDataSource(retrofit);

        //When
        remoteDataSource.getTopicsRx().subscribe(mSubscriber);

        //Then
        mSubscriber.assertNoErrors();
        mSubscriber.assertCompleted();
    }

}
```

You can check my example in [GitHub](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/Dagger2RxJava) and [this tutorial](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/#sthash.aQy5xLsu.dpbs).

Also In the presenter you can see my server call with RxJava:

```
public class TopicPresenter implements TopicContract.Presenter {

    @NonNull
    private TopicContract.View mView;

    @NonNull
    private BaseSchedulerProvider mSchedulerProvider;

    @NonNull
    private CompositeSubscription mSubscriptions;

    @NonNull
    private RemoteDataSource mRemoteDataSource;


    public TopicPresenter(@NonNull RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource, @NonNull TopicContract.View view, @NonNull BaseSchedulerProvider provider) {
        this.mRemoteDataSource = checkNotNull(remoteDataSource, "remoteDataSource");
        this.mView = checkNotNull(view, "view cannot be null!");
        this.mSchedulerProvider = checkNotNull(provider, "schedulerProvider cannot be null");

        mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();

        mView.setPresenter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void fetch() {

        Subscription subscription = mRemoteDataSource.getTopicsRx()
                .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.computation())
                .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
                .subscribe((List<Topics> listTopics) -> {
                            mView.setLoadingIndicator(false);
                            mView.showTopics(listTopics);
                        },
                        (Throwable error) -> {
                            try {
                                mView.showError();
                            } catch (Throwable t) {
                                throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
                            }

                        },
                        () -> {
                        });

        mSubscriptions.add(subscription);
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe() {
        fetch();
    }

    @Override
    public void unSubscribe() {
        mSubscriptions.clear();
    }

}
```

And now TopicPresenterTest:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TopicPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    private RemoteDataSource mRemoteDataSource;

    @Mock
    private TopicContract.View mView;

    private BaseSchedulerProvider mSchedulerProvider;

    TopicPresenter mThemePresenter;

    List<Topics> mList;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        Topics topics = new Topics(1, "Discern The Beach");
        Topics topicsTwo = new Topics(2, "Discern The Football Player");
        mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mList.add(topics);
        mList.add(topicsTwo);

        mSchedulerProvider = new ImmediateSchedulerProvider();
        mThemePresenter = new TopicPresenter(mRemoteDataSource, mView, mSchedulerProvider);


    }

    @Test
    public void fetchData() {

        when(mRemoteDataSource.getTopicsRx())
                .thenReturn(rx.Observable.just(mList));

        mThemePresenter.fetch();

        InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mView);
        inOrder.verify(mView).setLoadingIndicator(false);
        inOrder.verify(mView).showTopics(mList);

    }

    @Test
    public void fetchError() {

        when(mRemoteDataSource.getTopicsRx())
                .thenReturn(Observable.error(new Throwable("An error has occurred!")));
        mThemePresenter.fetch();

        InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mView);
        inOrder.verify(mView).showError();
        verify(mView, never()).showTopics(anyList());
    }

}
```

You can check my example in [GitHub](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/Dagger2RxJava) and [this article.](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/unit-testing-retrofit-rxjava/)

Answer (score 1):

Solution be @maciekjanusz is perfect along with explanation, so I will only say this, the problem occurs when you use `Schedulers.io()` and `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`. The problem with @maciekjanusz's answer is that it's too complex to understand and still not everyone uses Dagger2 (which they should). Also, I'm not too sure but with RxJava2 my imports for `RxJavaHooks` wasn't working.

Better solution for RxJava2:-

Add [RxSchedulersOverrideRule](https://gist.github.com/rohankandwal/1aadd4fbcff7cc35c794ff9213ecb129) to your test package and just add the following line in your test class.

```
@Rule
public RxSchedulersOverrideRule schedulersOverrideRule = new RxSchedulersOverrideRule();
```

That's it, nothing else to add, your test cases should be running fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with

.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

i fixed it with the following codes

```
public class RxJavaUtils {
    public static Supplier<Scheduler> getSubscriberOn = () -> Schedulers.io();
    public static Supplier<Scheduler> getObserveOn = () -> AndroidSchedulers.mainThread();
}
```

and use it like this

```
deviceService.findDeviceByCode(text)
            .subscribeOn(RxJavaUtils.getSubscriberOn.get())
            .observeOn(RxJavaUtils.getObserveOn.get())
```

and in my test

```
@Before
public void init(){
    getSubscriberOn = () -> Schedulers.from(command -> command.run()); //Runs in curren thread
    getObserveOn = () -> Schedulers.from(command -> command.run()); //runs also in current thread
}
```

works also for io.reactivex