# Mockito test case for DAO class methods written using java 8

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
public class DBConnectionDAOImpl {

public List<String> getData{
    return jdbcTemplate.query("Select abc from table_name ", (ResultSet rs) -> getAllData(rs));
}

public List<String> getAllData(ResultSet rs){
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        while(rs.next()){
            ls.add(rs.getString("pk"));
        }
        return ls;
    }catch(Exception e){


    }
}
```

}

For testing getData method I have written test case as:

```
public class DBConnectionDAOImplTest {

@InjectMock
DBConnectionDAOImpl dbConnectionDAOImpl;

@MOck
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Test
public void getDataTest(){
    ResultSet rs = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
    when(rs.next().thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false));
    when(rs.getString("pk")).thenReturn("someVal");
    when(dbConnectionDAOImpl.getAllData(rs)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<String>());
    when(jdbcTemplate.query("Select abc from table_name ", (ResultSet rs) -> dbConnectionDAOImpl.getAllData(rs))).thenReturn(new ArrayList<String>());

    List<String> result = dbConnectionDAOImpl.getData();
    assertNotNull(result);
}
```

}

while running the test case I am getting the error in line

```
when(dbConnectionDAOImpl.getAllData(rs)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<String>());
```

as "org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:". Not getting where exactly I am getting wrong.

--- EDIT 1--
after changing the

```
 when(dbConnectionDAOImpl.getAllData(rs)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<String>());
```

as per the comment assertion is failing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when I run mockito test occurs WrongTypeOfReturnValue Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121772/when-i-run-mockito-test-occurs-wrongtypeofreturnvalue-exception)

Answer (score 1):

As in provided link in my comment, try to change:

```
when(dbConnectionDAOImpl.getAllData(rs)).thenReturn(new ArrayList<String>());
```

to

```
doReturn(new ArrayList<String>()).when(dbConnectionDAOImpl).getAllData(rs)
```

Comment: Changed as per your comment now error is gone but result is null that's why assertion is failing.

Comment: Put full code of your class and test, you're missing some objects and I don't know if you're mocking it, stubbing or do nothing. For me it seems that you have more issues here.