# mocking HttpClient request

Tags: spring, mockito

I'm trying to write tests for my app, but get this error.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
String cannot be returned by getContent()
getContent() should return InputStream
```

At this line.

```
Mockito.when(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity)).thenReturn("");
```

This is the service method.

```
public String calculate(params) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
//some logic
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
request.setConfig(config);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
}
```

This is my test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TestApplication {
  @Mock
  HttpClient httpClient;

  @Mock
  HttpResponse httpResponse;

  @Mock
  HttpEntity httpEntity;

  @InjectMocks
  AppService appService;

  @Test
  public void geocode() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(httpClient.execute(any())).thenReturn(httpResponse);
    Mockito.when(httpResponse.getEntity()).thenReturn(httpEntity);
    Mockito.when(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity)).thenReturn("test_string");

    String result = appService.calculate("param string", "json", "key");

    Assert.assertEquals("test_string", result);
  }
}
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121772/when-i-run-mockito-test-occurs-wrongtypeofreturnvalue-exception) advice and replacing with script doesn't help. Fails to compile with `Expression expected`.

```
Mockito.doReturn("test_string").when(EntityUtils).toString(httpEntity);
```

And this

```
Mockito.doReturn("test_string").when(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
```

fails with

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better way is do not mock the `HttpClient`. It makes the test very ugly and difficult to understand. Use a real `HttpClient` instance and mock the external API using tools likes [WireMock](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock) or [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver).

I usually use MockWebServer. It is very fast just like unit test.Something like below :

```java
public class TestApplication {
    
    
    private MockWebServer server;

    @Test
    public void geocode(){

        MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();
        server.start();
        HttpUrl baseUrl = server.url("/");

        //stub the server to return the expected HTTP request
        server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("some-expected-response"));

       //continues execute your test
       String result = appService.calculate("param string", "json", "key");

       // Verify that appService really send out the correct request 
       RecordedRequest request = server.takeRequest();
       assertEquals("/xxxxxx", request.getPath()); 
       ....


    }
}
```