# How to init a mock of a real class

Tags: java, testng, mockito

I want to mock a concrete class in a TestNG test case. The class could look like this (simplified example):

```
public class Example() {

  private MyHello myHello;

  public Example(MyHello myHello) {
    this.myHello = myHello;
  }

  public String doSomething() {
    return myHello.doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

Now we want to mock `Example` return some defined value:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
  this.example = mock(Example.class);
  when(this.example.doSomething()).thenReturn("dummyValue");
}
```

This *looks* quite good but in fact it isn't. The last line in the setup method calls the method on an instance of `Example`, this instance didn't get an `MyHello` through the constructor and so I get a NPE in the setUp method.

Is there a way to either inject an `MyHello` while creating the mock or to disallow Mockito calling the method on a *real* instance?

**Edit**

*The issue, that caused the observed behaviour was, that the `doSomething()` method is actually `final`. I overlooked that when I tried to solve that issue. [And this is a known limitation with mockito anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3794448/105224). So I'll either remove the finals or extract an interface for that class.*

Comment: Did you actually run your example? Does it produce the NPE?
It shouldn't, unless Mockito interacts with CDI/Guice in a weird way.

Comment: Yes, I actually run into the NPE. It should work this way? I think I'll clean up my whole environment (again) and try again.

Comment: Problem solved (facepalm). The method `doSomething()` is `final`. I overlooked that. And this is a well known limitation (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3794448/105224)

Comment: Let me correct this a limitation of the JVM itself, as we are not rewriting bytecode, which is the way Powermock works (it reloads modified classes in new classloader by the way)

Answer (score 2):

See if using `doReturn("dummy").when(example).doSomething()` does the trick.

[Mockito.doReturn](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn%28java.lang.Object%29)

From JavaDoc:

> Use doReturn() in those rare occasions when you cannot use when(Object). 
>   Beware that when(Object) is always recommended for stubbing because it is argument type-safe and more readable (especially when stubbing consecutive calls).
>
> Here are those rare occasions when doReturn() comes handy:
>
> 1. When spying real objects and calling real methods on a spy brings side effects
>
>    List list = new LinkedList();
>
>    List spy = spy(list);
>
>    //Impossible: real method is called so spy.get(0) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException (the list is yet empty)
>      when(spy.get(0)).thenReturn("foo");
>
>    //You have to use doReturn() for stubbing:
>      doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from `spy` keyword instead of `mock`.

As far as I'm concerned from the documentation of Mockito, you are able to make partial mock with spy.

For detailed explanation you can benefit from subject 13 in the [doc](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.7/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html) of it.

Comment: Not exactly - in my case, calling the real method is not wanted. And that's what a spy would do. I want to train a mock so that it returns a dummy value if the method is called with some expected values.