# Stubbing Out a Null-Returning Function in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I've been using JUnit and Mockito in an attempt to test how a particular networking module affects its input and output streams.  To facilitate testing, I've created a set of mock network object streams (i.e. an instance of an [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and an instance of an [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject%28java.lang.Object%29)) and stubbed out the methods I want to be testing in a fashion similar to the following code snippet:

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.junit.Test;  

public class NetworkTester
{
    @Test
    public void ModuleRespondsToServerRequest() throws Exception
    {
        ObjectInputStream mockClientIn = mock(ObjectInputStream.class);
        ObjectOutputStream mockClientOut = mock(ObjectOutputStream.class);

        when(mockClientIn.readObject()).thenReturn("Sent from Server");

        // Initialize module and connect it to the network...

        verify(mockClientOut, timeout(100).atLeastOnce()).writeObject(isNotNull());
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile and run this code, I get a null pointer exception at the line "when(mockClientIn.readObject()).thenReturn("Sent from Server");".  I believe that this is caused by the fact that the "readObject()" function is returning a null pointer when called on the stubbed object, but I don't know if it's possible to bypass this behavior.

Is there any way to stub this function (or similar null returning functions) using Mockito?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That's how Mockito works, and that's how you specify behavior. What is the specific stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito cannot mock `readObject()` since it is final. You could try [PowerMockito](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.7/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html) or consider redesigning your code for easier testability. See a discussion on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking).

Answer (score 2):

If you do a view source you will notice that the method is final.

```
public final Object readObject()
```

Try wrapping the dependency with another object.
See: [Final method mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking)