# How to just check the method invocation without executing when spied in Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit4, spy

I am trying to test the just the invocation of a final method to be verified. I do not want to execute that.

```
//First I spied the test class.
TestClass testClass =  spy(new TestClass());

//I did something like
doNothing().when(testClass ).method1(parameter);
...
//but in the following line I found the actual method1 is invoked and exceptions are thrown
verify(testClass ).method1(parameter);
```

How to just check the method1 invocation without executing when spied?

Thank You !

Comment: Can you include the actual TestClass in your question? It might explain things.  For example, if method1 is final, you would get this behavior.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking