# How to mock another method in the same class which is being tested?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am writing JUnit Test case for a class which has two methods methodA,methodB.
I would like to mock the call to the methodB from methodA in my test case 
I am using spy on the class which I am testing, but still the methodB gets executed.

here is the class

```
 public class SomeClass
{

     public Object methodA(Object object) 
    {
         object=methodB(object);

        return object;
    }



    public Object methodB(Object object) 
    {
        //do somthing
        return object;
    }
}
```

here is the test class

```
  @RunWith( org.powermock.modules.junit4.legacy.PowerMockRunner.class )
    @PrepareForTest(SomeClass.class)
    public class SomeClassTest { 

        private SomeClass var = null; 


        @Before
        public void setUp() {

            var=new SomeClass();

        }

        @After
        public void tearDown()
            {
            var= null;

        }

        @Test
        public void testMethodA_1()
            throws Exception {
            Object object =new Object();
        SomeClass spy_var=PowerMockito.spy(var);
        PowerMockito.when(spy_var.methodB(object)).thenReturn(object);

    Object result = var.methodA(object);        

        assertNotNull(result);

        }

    }
```

The method B still gets the called though I have mocked it 
PLease suggest me a solution with the proper way of mocking the methodB call from methodA of the same class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this yesterday, for spies is best to do:

`doReturn(X).when(spy).method(any())`

Comment: And when I am testing should I use Object result=var.methodA(object);        
or Object result = spy_var.methodA(object);

Comment: you shoukd use spy_var

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/   Works with mockito and allows private, static and constructor mocking.

Comment: PowerMockito is a class in powermock

Answer (score 10):

Taking this approach will result in brittle tests which will need to change if you refactor your class under test. I would highly recommend that you try to assert your expected test results by checking state of `SomeClass` rather than relying on mocks.

If you do indeed need to mock `MethodB` then this is an indication that maybe the behaviour in `MethodB` actually belongs in a separate class which you could then test the interaction of `SomeClass` with via mocks

if you do indeed need to do what you ask for then a PartialMock is what you want.

you probably want to create a partial mock of some class but indicate that calls to `MethodA` should call the actual method but then mock `MethodB`

You can see how to use them in the [Mockito documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.11/org/mockito/Mockito.html#partial_mocks)

As stated in their documentation though Partial mocks are a code smell, though they have identified some explicit use cases.

Answer (score 8):

As per [@Totoro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23958710/6654475), this is just a summary here.

1. Annotate the object for the class you are testing with the `@Spy` annotation.

So this:

```
@Spy
@InjectMocks
MyClassUnderTest myClassUnderTest;
```

instead of just

```
@InjectMocks
MyClassUnderTest myClassUnderTest;
```

2. Use `doReturn()` instead of `when.thenReturn()` whenever asking for the mocked object from the class spyed on (class under test).

`doReturn(X).when(myClassUnderTest).method(any())`

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same challenge. Have a look at this solution which will work for newer testing suit versions.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
<version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Solution-

```
//when- then for MethodA test
SomeClass spy_var=Mockito.spy(var);
doReturn(X).when(spy_var).methodB(object)
Object result = spy_var.methodA(object);
//assertions on result
```