# mock methods in same class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am using Mockito to mock a method in the same class for which I am writing test. I have seen other answers on SO ([Mocking method in the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958611/how-to-mock-another-method-in-the-same-class-which-is-being-tested)), but probably I am misunderstanding them, since I running into issues.

```
 class Temp() {

    public boolean methodA(String param) {

         try {

             if(methodB(param))
                   return true;

             return false;
         } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
 }
```

My Test method:

```
 @Test
 public void testMethodA() {

    Temp temp = new Temp();
    Temp spyTemp = Mockito.spy(temp);

    Mockito.doReturn(true).when(spyTemp).methodB(Mockito.any()); 
    boolean status = temp.methodA("XYZ");

    Assert.assertEquals(true, status);
 }
```

I however get the expection printed out because definition of methodB gets executed.
My understanding is definition of methodB would get mocked by using spyTemp. However that does not appear to be the case.

Can someone please explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The first issue is that you have to use spyTemp object to expect something from Mockito. Here it is not the same as test. `spyTemp` is wrapped by the Mockito object `temp`.

Another issue is that you stub only `methodB()`, but you are trying to run `methodA()`. Yes in your implementation of `methodA()` you call methodB(), but you call `this.methodB()`, not `spyTemp.methodB()`.
Here you have to understand that mocking would work only when you call it on the instance of `temp`. It's wrapped by a Mockito proxy which catches your call, and if you have overriden some method, it will call your new implementation instead of the original one. But since the original method is called, inside it you know nothing about Mockito proxy. So your "overriden" method would be called only when you run `spyTemp.methodB()`

This should work:

```
Mockito.doReturn(true).when(spyTemp).methodB(Mockito.any()); 
boolean status = spyTemp.methodA("XYZ");
```

Comment: Do you mean `spyTemp.methodA("XYZ")` rather than `spyTemp.methodB("XYZ")`?

Comment: Yup it should be ```spyTemp.methodA("XYZ")```

Comment: "Here you have to understand that mocking would work only when you call it on the instance of temp."
Did you mean to call on the instance spyTemp, not temp ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. spyTemp.methodA("XYZ") should be there.

Answer (score 23):

You created a spy and mocked `methodB()`. That is correct! But you called `methodA()` on the original object. To get the correct result call it on the spy

```
boolean status = spyTemp.methodA("XYZ");
```

Answer (score 9):

Note the following from Mockito documentation:

> Mockito *does not* delegate calls to the passed real instance, instead
>   it actually creates a copy of it. So if you keep the real instance and
>   interact with it, don't expect the spied to be aware of those
>   interaction and their effect on real instance state. The corollary is
>   that when an *unstubbed* method is called *on the spy* but *not on the
>   real instance*, you won't see any effects on the real instance.

This is referring specifically to your situation. You keep a reference to `temp` and then call its `methodA`. Mockito is not spying on that instance at all; it's spying on `spyTemp`. So the normal `methodB` is called.

Note that you should avoid partial mocks altogether for new code.