# Mockito mocking the value of a method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Class under test:

```
class FruitQuality {

  void testQuality() {
    getfruits();
    //some code
  }

  List<Fruits> getfruits() {
    return orange;
  }
}
```

Below is the test code. I mocked the class class under test and overridden a return value for the method getfruits. But when I run the mock, I don't get  the expected mocked return value. Easymock can substitute return values for methods of class under test, if those are explicitly mocked. How can I get the mocked return value when I mock the real object method.

```
@Test
public void test() {
  Fruits fruit= new Fruits();
  fruit.setFruit("orange");
  List<Fruits> fruitsList = new ArrayList<Fruits>();
  fruitsList.add(fruit);

  Fruits mock = Mockito.mock(FruitQuality.class)
  classUnderTest = new FruitQuality();
  when(mock.getfruits()).thenReturn(fruitsList);

  result= classUnderTest.getfruits();
  assertEquals(result, fruitsList);
}
```

Comment: is our assertEquals correct? It calls for `result` but there is no variable `result`

Comment: why do you mock the class under test? you usually mock the dependencies of class under test

Comment: Please make sure your code is somewhat real Java code, your `getfruits()` method is returning two values using two `return` statements. That doesn't exist in Java...

Comment: You make a mock, add a mocked return, but does the mock ever get called? *- not in this code -*

Comment: I want to do test for the testQuality method

Comment: How to call the mock when I call the real class object

Comment: Why do you want to use a mock if you have a real object? What is according to you the usage for a mocked object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock another method in the same class which is being tested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958611/how-to-mock-another-method-in-the-same-class-which-is-being-tested)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when writing unit tests, you have one class under test containing the implementation code you are testing, while mocking the methode of other classes your class under test is relying on.

Refering to your example you would have a class

```
public class FruitQuality {
    private FruitProvider fruitProvider;

    public List<Fruit> testQuality() {
        List<Fruit> fruits = fruitProvider.getfruits();
        /* Some code doing something with fruits, e.g., filtering. */
        return fruits;
    }
}
```

And a second class

```
public class FruitProvider {
    public List<Fruits> getfruits() {
        /* Returning some fruits ... */
    }
}
```

Now, you could mock your Provider to test your class under test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FruitQualityUnitTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private FruitQuality fruitQuality;
    @Mock
    private FruitProvider fruitProvider;

    @Test
    public void testQuality() {
        /* Mocking the provider. */
        Fruits fruit= new Fruits();
        fruit.setFruit("orange");
        List<Fruits> fruitsList = new ArrayList<Fruits>();
        fruitsList.add(fruit);
        when(fruitProvider.getFruits()).thenReturn(fruitsList);

        /* Invoke the method under test. */
        List<Fruits> result = fruitProvider.testQuality();

        /* Assert that some methods where called. */
        verify(fruitProvider, times(1)).getFruits();

        /* If the method would return a value, you can do some assertions based on the mocked method calls. */
        assertEquals(result, fruitsList);
    }
}
```

If you want to test methods of the same object you are mocking, you can use the @Spy annotation instead of @Mock, assuring that only methods you are explicitely mocking doing other things than the original implementation.