# Mockito: mocking a method of same class called by method under test when using @InjectMocks

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class I want to test that has several external dependencies, and a couple internal methods. I would like to write a test for `MethodA`, but *not* have Method A's internal call to `MethodB` to actually exercise `MethodB`. I'd like to mock/stub `MethodB` and return something specific instead. Usually I'd use `when/thenReturn` but it doesn't behave like I expect - it actually jumps into Method B while creating the mock itself.

**MyService.java**

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Autowired
  private ServiceA serviceA;

  @Autowired
  private ServiceB serviceB;

    public SomeObject methodA() {
      // some logic using serviceA.method and serviceB.method that creates "output"
      SomeObject someObject = methodB(output);
      return someObject;
    }

    public SomeObject methodB(SomeObject someObject) {
      // deep mysteries done here to someObject
      return someObject 
    }
}
```

**MyServiceTest.java**

```
public class MyServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private ServiceA serviceA;

  @Mock
  private ServiceB serviceB;

  @InjectMocks
  private MyService myService;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void methodATest() {
    when(serviceA.method()).thenReturn(stuff);
    when(serviceB.method()).thenReturn(otherStuff);

    // here is what I would like to do
    when(myService.methodB()).thenReturn(mockedSomeObject); //<- doesn't work

    assertThat(myService.methodA().getSomeObjectProperty())
        .isEqualTo("property");
  }
}
```

I've looked at solutions that manually mock the `MyService` class with `Mockito.mock(MyService.class)`, but (as the above example is obviously contrived) my actual class has quite a few external dependencies and I'd prefer a solution that still allows me to mock the service using `@Mock` for the `@Autowired` dependencies and `@InitMocks` for the class under test, unless it's simply not possible.

I've tried:

```
Mockito.doReturn(mockedSomeObject).when(myService.methodB(any(SomeObject.class));
```

but that also steps into MethodB when creating the mock for that method, which shouldn't be happening.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try Adding @Spy to your InjectMocks and use the object to "expect" them in a slightly different syntax.

`import org.mockito.Spy;`

```
 @InjectMocks
 @Spy
 private MyService myService;
```

And now mock the service call

```
 Mockito.doReturn(mockedSomeObject).when(myService).methodB();
```

Also change the other mock call to this

```
Mockito.doReturn(stuff).when(serviceA).method();
Mockito.doReturn(otherStuff).when(serviceB).method();
```

Comment: Thank you - I had tried each of these changes on their own, but never together - this worked perfectly!

Comment: Happy that i was able to help you.

Comment: @lrathod , there is any difference between using `when(serviceA.method()).ThenReturn(stuff)` and `doReturn(stuff).when(serviceA).method()` ??

Comment: @Eric, When you are using the "Spy" , you will need to use the latter. Functionally both does the same though.

Comment: AFAIK you wouldn't need to replace the mock calls to the other mocked `serviceA` and `serviceB`. Then remain as mocks (not spies), so there is no difference between `thenReturn` and `doReturn`

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark your object as Spy or explicitly create a Spy object for it using `MyClass objA=null;
MyClass spy_objA=Powermockito.spy(objA)
doReturn(what_you_want).when(spy_objA).method()`

Edit: Can find a similar question you may want to check
[How to mock another method in the same class which is being tested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958611/how-to-mock-another-method-in-the-same-class-which-is-being-tested?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks for the idea - however I'd prefer not to use PowerMockito unless there is really no way to accomplish this with "regular" Mockito.