# How to mock a method of the same class?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

In the testing method, there are methods of the same class. How to mock the methods of the same class?

An example is as follows.

I am testing method2. It involves method1 which is in the same class. How to mock this method1?

```
public class A
{
  public void method1(int a, int b){

  }

  public void method2(){

      int value = method1(10,20);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Spy](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.1.0/org/mockito/Spy.html) to do this, in combination with `doReturn` to stub out the method for which you want to provide canned behavior.  There are many examples available on how to use a spy.  Check out these tutorials and documentation:

- [Mockito: mocking a method of same class called by method under test when using @InjectMocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683842/mockito-mocking-a-method-of-same-class-called-by-method-under-test-when-using)
- https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy
- [Mockito: Trying to spy on method is calling the original method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620103/mockito-trying-to-spy-on-method-is-calling-the-original-method)

Example:

```
   List list = new LinkedList();
   List spy = spy(list);

   //Use doReturn to change the behavior of a method call
   doReturn("foo").when(spy).get(0);
```