# How to mock method in the same class that returns an Iterator in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to unit test a method `getFruitItemMap()` which calls another method `getAllItemsBelongingToFruit` whose return type is `Iterator` in the same class. I am trying to mock this method using `Mockito.spy()`, but unsure of how to return an Iterator. I checked other answers on [stack overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958611/how-to-mock-another-method-in-the-same-class-which-is-being-tested), but looks like I am missing something here.

```
class FruitItemImpl {

Map<String, Fruit> getFruitItemMap() {
        Map<String, Fruit> fruitMap = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator<Fruit> items = getAllItemsBelongingToFruit("Apple");

while (items.hasNext()) {
            Fruit fruitItem = items.next();
            fruitMap.put(fruitItem.getID(), fruitItem);
        }
        return fruitMap;
    }

public Iterator<Fruit> getAllItemsBelongingToFruit(String fruit) {
      //some logic that returns an iterator
}
```

Here is the unit test:

```
    @Test
    public void testGetFruitItemMap() {
        Map<String, Fruit> fruitItemMap = new HashMap<>();
        FruitItemImpl doa1 = Mockito.spy(dao);
   Mockito.doReturn(**new Iterator<Fruit>**).when(doa1).getAllItemsBelongingToFruit("Apple") //Here
        Assert.assertEquals(fruitItemMap.size(), doa1.getFruitItemMap().size());
    }
```

Since I am new to Mockito and Unit Testing world, trying to get my head around it. I am not sure how to make mockito return an iterator `Mockito.doReturn()` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have a collection of the appropriate `Fruit` objects, and return an `Iterator` from it. In your case, you could just return an iterator from the `fruitItemMap`'s `values()` you're using in your test:

```
@Test
public void testGetFruitItemMap() {
    Map<String, Fruit> fruitItemMap = new HashMap<>();
    FruitItemImpl doa1 = Mockito.spy(dao);
    Mockito.doReturn(fruitItemMap.values().iterator()) // Here!
           .when(doa1).getAllItemsBelongingToApple("Apple");
    Assert.assertEquals(fruitItemMap.size(), doa1.getFruitItemMap().size());
}
```