# mockito can't match overloaded method

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock a `SimpleDateFormat` object but Mockito says I have the wrong number of args.  Code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat spyDateFormat = spy(new SimpleDateFormat(DateFormatManager.MAIN_ACTIVITY_TITLE_FORMAT));
 // exception points to below line
 when(spyDateFormat.format(any(Date.class))).thenReturn("foo format");
```

exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
```

The method exists in DateFormat, its parent:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)

Fiddled around with switching to DateFormat, using `spy`.  No luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`format(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) method is `final`, so Mockito cannot spy it.

Comment: I just want to add: You may want to have a look at PowerMock if you need to mock final methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking

Answer (score 2):

> From the Mockito FAQ:

**What are the limitations of Mockito**

Cannot mock final methods - their real behavior is executed without any exception. Mockito cannot warn you about mocking final methods so be vigilant.