# Mock final method - Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, testng, final

I want to mock final method of a class. I tried

```
PowerMockito.mock(mockedClass.class)
```

But it is not working for me. It is giving `NullPointerException`. I am using TestNG to run my test cases.

Comment: Duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking

Comment: Just a little detail: PowerMockito helps you solve problems that you should not have. It's kind of like putting perfume on something that stinks. You might not smell it anymore, but the underlying problem is still there. Sometimes that's life, especially with less-than-well designed external libraries, but if you can do it another way, chances are, that way is better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Final method mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking)

Answer (score 4):

According to Mockito documentation on final types and methods [here](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.12.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39) it is possible to enable mocking of final classes and final methods by use the following dependency `mockito-inline` instead of `mockito-core`. I tried to do that and succeeded in mocking both a final class and a final method even without `PowerMockito`.

I used the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and ran tests using JDK 8.

Perhaps that may help you.

Comment: can you tell me where can I add this depedency?

Comment: what build tool do you use to run your tests?

Comment: I am using TestNG

Comment: I mean Maven, Gradle or something like that. Do you have pom.xml or build.gradle in your project ?

Comment: No, I don't hjave such files.

Comment: And how do you run your project - from IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse or any other way ?

Comment: I am running it from Eclipse.

Comment: And how do you add Mockito to your project ? As a jar file or some other way ?

Comment: As a jar I have added Mockito. "mockito-all-1.9.5.jar"

Comment: OK, please try to upgrade your mockito jar to version 2.12.0 and include one more jar - "mockito-inline-2.12.0.jar" that can be downloaded from this page: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-inline/2.12.0.

Comment: Ok. I have upgraded my mockito.jar. But it is giving error while running my project.

Comment: Error comes when I am addig mockito-inline-2.12.0.jar

Comment: Please could you provide these errors ?

Comment: FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.getStackTraceCleanerProvider(Plugins.java:17)
 at org.mockito.internal.exceptions.stacktrace.StackTraceFilter.<clinit>(StackTraceFilter.java:21)

Comment: Pretty strange, perhaps after upgrade it conflicts with some of other dependencies - do you still keep powermock dependency in your project ?

Comment: I need to keep. Because I want to mock static method.

Comment: OK, please try to upgrade powermock either. Here is a page to download jar from: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.7.3 It seems to be compatible with mockito 2.12.0 version. In case it won't work, please share your code (if it is possible) via GitHub or some other public service - that will help to solve your issue.