# Why do I get an UnifnishedStubException in Mockito when the stub looks as per documentation?

Tags: java, testing, mockito, tdd, stub

I have the following test file using Mockito framework:

```
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();

    @Spy    
    private JarExtracter jExt = Mockito.spy(JarExtracter.class);

    @Test
    public void inputStreamTest() throws IOException {
        String path = "/edk.dll";       

        // Call the method and do the checks                    
        jExt.extract(path);                 

        // Check for error with a null stream
        path = "/../edk.dll";       
        doThrow(IOException.class).when(jExt).extract(path);   
        jExt.extract(path);

        verifyNoMoreInteractions(jExt);        
        expectedException.expect(IOException.class);
        expectedException.expectMessage("Cannot get");
```

`doThrow()` line returns:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at confusionIndicator.tests.JarExtracterTests.inputStreamTest(JarExtracterTests.java:30)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

I tried different approaches to testing this error throwing behaviour, but I just cannot get rid of this error message which makes my test fail. Any help will be substantially appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken here - why are you **invoking** your "method under test" ( ` jExt.extract(path); `) **before** you specify the mock behavior?!

Answer (score 1):

With your code as written, I added in the following stub for `JarExtractor`, and the code ran fine, giving the IOException you'd expect:

```
class JarExtracter {
    public void extract(String path) throws IOException{

    }
}
```

Replacing this with the following, I get the same UnfinishedStubbingException as you:

```
class JarExtracter {
    final public void extract(String path) throws IOException{

    }
}
```

---edit--- Likewise if the method is static:

```
class JarExtracter {
    public static void extract(String path) throws IOException{

    }
}
```

As you say in your comment, your method is static, so you won't be able to mock it with Mockito.
Here's some good advice on ways forward [for dealing with final methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking), and here's some on [mocking static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito).

Comment: No, it is: `public static void extract(String resourceName) throws IOException {`

Comment: Ah, you also can't mock static methods with Mockito.  I'll add that to my answer.