# Spring Mockito Mocked object keeps calling real method

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have tried to look all over stackoverflow and none of the answer solves my problem.
For some reason, my mocked object is invoking the actual method when `when` was invoked. And this is calling the test to throw `NullPointerException`.

The offending line is this: `when(fileReader.readLines(any(Path.class))).thenReturn(lines);`

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and How I can fix this issue?

Below are the minimally code required to run the test

FileReaderTest.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;

public class FileReaderTest {
    @Test 
    public void mockTest() throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader = mock(FileReader.class);
        Stream.Builder<String> stream = Stream.builder();
        stream.add("\n");
        Stream<String> lines = stream.build();
        when(fileReader.readLines(any(Path.class))).thenReturn(lines);
    }
}
```

FileReader.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class FileReader {

    private FileReader() {}

    public static final FileReader newInstance() {
        return new FileReader();
    }

    public final Stream<String> readLines(Path filePath) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("readLines");
        final FileInputStream fileInputStream 
                = new FileInputStream(filePath.toFile()); 
        final InputStreamReader inputStreamReader 
                = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        return reader.lines();
    }
}
```

STDOUT

```
> Task :test                                                                                          

FileReaderTest > mockTest() STANDARD_OUT                              
    readLines                                      

FileReaderTest > mockTest() FAILED                                    
    java.lang.NullPointerException                 
        at FileReader.readLines(FileReader.java:25)                   
        at FileReaderTest.mockTest(FileReaderTest.java:43)
```

Comment: What stands in line 43 in FileReaderTest? Where are you calling the `readLines` in your test?

Comment: @alea `when(fileReader.readLines(any(Path.class))).thenReturn(lines);` this is the line that is throwing error due to nullpointer exception on the parameter that was passed into the method.

Comment: if the method is mocked, then it shouldn't be calling the actual method and giving nullpointerexception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Final method mocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793791/final-method-mocking)

Comment: @alea yap thanks. I didn't know `final` key word here refers to the method. not the return type.